# Optional Parameter

Tags: php, optional-parameters

I'm writing a php function with an optional parameter and can't seem to get it to work.

```
function myFunc($param,$optional){
    $var = $optional || [];
}
```

The logic is if it's called with the `$optional` param it sets `$var` get set the value of `$optional` if left blank `$var` get set to new array `[]`. I'm getting an undefined variable `$var` though.

**Question:** Why can't I declare an optional param in my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare a parameter optional in the function parameters. It doesn't work because you have to told the PHP interpreter to expect a parameter.

```
function myFunc($param, $optional = null){
    // ...
}
```

In PHP 7+ you can use the spread operator for argument unpacking to denote optional parameters. This is better than sending an array of arguments to a function.

```
function myFunc($param, ...$optional){
    print_r($optional);
}

myFunc('baz'); // Array ( )
myFunc('baz', 'foo', 'foobar', 'whoo'); // Array ( [0] => foo [1] => foobar [2] => whoo )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
function myFunc($param, $optional = '') {
    $var = $optional;
    if ($var == '') {
      $var = [];
    }
}
//without parameter
myFunc('abc');
//with parameter
myFunc('abc', 'optional param');
```

generic example:

`function myFunc($param, $optional1 = '', $optional2 = []) {`

in general try to keep all optional parameters at end